# angular2 how to access a json child

Tags: json, angular

I would like to access a json child using Angular2, here is what I tried:

**my json :**

```
orderList=
{
  "ref1": {
       "Id": "57987"
       "order": [
          {
           "amount": 4900,
           "parent": "CIDPT8AO"
          }
        ]
   }
 }
```

**in the view:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of orderList">
  <td>{{order[0]}}</td>  // NOT OKAY
</tr>
```

I would like to access "Id" and "parent", any idea?

Comment: I think first you have to declare the `orderList` as an array

Comment: what is your class structure ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you're missing a , after the "Id" line.

You're trying to access a JSON object like an array. Not sure if that works with Angular... If the error is not solved by adding the , I mentioned above, try declaring your orderList as an array.

If you're bound to this format you could do it like that:

```
orderListValues = Object.keys(orderList).map(function(_) { return j[_]; })
```

Then you should be able to access the values like that:

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of orderListValues">
  <td>{{order.Id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Example:

```js
orderList = {
  "ref1": {
   "Id": "57987",
   "order": [
      {
       "amount": 4900,
       "parent": "CIDPT8AO"
      }
    ]
   }
};
orderListValues = Object.keys(orderList).map(function(_) { return orderList[_]; });
console.log(orderListValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your orderList is an object, you need

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of orderList.ref1.order">
  <td>{{order}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this approach :**

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let order of obj">
  <td>{{order.Id}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Component**

```
var orderList=
{
  "ref1": {
       "Id": "57987",
       "order": [
          {
           "amount": 4900,
           "parent": "CIDPT8AO"
          }
        ]
   }
 };

 var obj = orderList[Object.keys(orderList)[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

NgForOf provides several exported values that can be aliased to local variables, for example:

**index: number** -> The index of the current item in the iterable.

**first: boolean** -> True when the item is the first item in the iterable.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let ref of orderList">
      <td>{{order.id}}</td> 
      <span *ngFor="let order of ref.order; let first = isFirst">
      <td *ngIf="isFirst">{{order.parent}}</td>
      </span>  
    </tr>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf